# Find and Replace Macro With Given List, Keeps Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, find

I very much am a macro noob and apologize for the likely dumb question.

I'm trying to build a macro that will find a replace a series of of footnote placeholders with the footnotes themselves, i.e.:

**Text**

> Before music recording artists like Billy Joel, The Police, Journey, and Kool & the Gang rose to international stardom, they transferred or licensed all of their sound recording copyrights to labels, via recording contracts, in exchange for royalties and advancements.**[mfn]1[\mfn]** The terms of such contracts are reflective of idiosyncratic negotiations, industry customs, and the weak bargaining power of recording artists compared to the record label.**[mfn]2[\mfn]** Even so, artists have a second bite at the apple: the Copyright Act of 1976 **[mfn]3[\mfn]** allows artists to terminate any prior grant “notwithstanding any agreement to the contrary” at least thirty-five years after the initial grant for works created “on or after January 1, 1978.”**[mfn]4[\mfn]** Termination rights safeguard authors and improve bargaining positions by giving authors a second opportunity “to negotiate more advantageous grants in their  works after the works ha[ve] been sufficiently ‘exploited’ to determine their ‘value.”’**[mfn]5[\mfn]**

I'm trying to replace each of the footnote holders with formatted text that could be plain, italicized, and even small caps. I would just manually cut and paste each, but there hundreds of footnotes per document and hundreds of documents. Right now, my intended replacement footnotes live in word tables at the bottom of each document but I gather I'll need to move them to an excel document where Column A are the footnote holders (i.e. [mfn]1[\mfn], [mfn]2[\mfn], etc.) and Column B is the text I want to replace the holders. However, that could be completely wrong.

I know it's common practice to insert the code I've already tried, but it's so hopeless it would be an insult to everyone. I'm having trouble: (1) writing a Word Macro to retrieve the values from a freestanding excel sheet; (2) keeping the source formatting; and (3) not wrecking everything in the process.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

**Update**

To clarify, I'm trying to create plain text footnotes for Wordpress from a document using alternative footnotes(i.e. not Word's default footnotes).

This is the code I'm using, and the issue I'm stuck is a error 5854 for a parameter string being too long (often the FNs are well over 250 characters):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WL_FN_Replace_Step_Two()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With msWord
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Open "D:\GMLR Website\Test.docx"
        .Activate

        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting

            For Each itm In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells

                .Text = itm.Value2                          

                .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, 1).Value2  

                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False

                .Execute Replace:=2     
            Next
        End With
        .Quit SaveChanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

So this is related to excel as this is the code to pull the strings from excel back into word. If I can get around the length issue, I should be able to get it to work.

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with Excel. Moreover, you description suggests you aren't using Word's footnote system at all, since that doesn't format footnotes as tables (which are not the same as Excel spreadhseets).

Comment: I updated the post with more information.

Comment: So why are you engaging in all this circumlocution when the simple expedient of using Word's footnote system, but replacing the footnote references with hyperlinks would suffice? See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/35915-post4.html

Comment: I wish I could, at least I don't think I can, because that's not how I get the documents. See example: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AilCXHOwgwu5gpYZ3iH8p_coLvb-wg?e=f5XT9E

But if there's an easier way to do it, I'm all ears. I've spent hours on this and can't seem to get past it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding that whoever wrote the document calls the notes footnotes, they're not - they're endnotes. Regardless, with a document such as that you could add your [mfn] & [\mfn] tags and the associated formatted text between them, with code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim h As Long, r As Long, RngD As Range, RngH As Range, RngT As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set RngD = .Range
  RngD.End = .Tables(.Tables.Count).Range.Start
  For h = RngD.Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(RngD.Hyperlinks(h).TextToDisplay) = True Then
      Set RngH = RngD.Hyperlinks(h).Range: Set RngT = Nothing
      With .Tables(.Tables.Count)
        For r = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
          If Split(.Cell(r, 1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = RngH.Text Then
            Set RngT = .Cell(r, 2).Range
            With RngT
              .End = .End - 1
              Do While .Characters.Last = vbCr
                .End = .End - 1
              Loop
            End With
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End With
      If Not RngT Is Nothing Then
        With RngH
          .Hyperlinks(1).Delete
          .Font.Reset
          .Text = "[mfn][\mfn]"
          .Start = .Start + 5
          .Collapse wdCollapseStart
          .FormattedText = RngT.FormattedText
          .InsertBefore h & " "
        End With
        RngT.Rows(1).Delete
      End If
    End If
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's not apparent whether you intend to retain the numbering. If not, delete or comment-out:

```
          .InsertBefore h & " "
```

Your sample document also has two 'footnotes' that are not connected to any references in the document. I've left those as they are.

Comment: This is perfect! You rock!

Answer (score -1):

There is a really easy way to do this and you don't need a macro. Here is a video that will help you however, it doesn't cover the main step to solve you specific problem (although it will help you a ton), for which I'll explain now.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do9ujnZLIC4

Here is what you will do:

1. Go into word
2. Go into mailings
3. Select start mail merge
4. Select Step-by-step mail merge wizard
5. Select letter (in this example I chose this one but use email if you want to send it via email)
6. Select Use the current document
7. Click next
8. Here you can import your excel list with the use existing list and the select a different list option
9. After clicking in select a different list look for your excel on the file explorer.
10. Make sure you have the first row is a header checked after you imported the list
11. Verify the information and click ok
12. Click next at the bottom
13. Put your cursor where you want the place holder to be
14. Click More items
15. Make sure you are in the imported list and click insert (you will have to go in and out to place the cursor where you want the place holder to be)
16. Click okay and next
17. Verify everything is in order
18. Click next and you can either print to pdf or select edit individual letter (you will get a document having all the information in the data base however you will receive it all in one document you could print it and send them individually but if you wanted to send it via email I would recommend you go back to step 5 and select email)

<----edit---->

here is a more complete video on this tool https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFqCvTOpOL0

Comment: That simply does not address the OP's problem. First, it requires the data to be taken out of the Word document it's already in and pasted into Excel - all on *one* row. Second, as if that's not bad enough, the mailmerge would destroy the very formatting the OP wants to retain.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what he was trying to do. I'm just trying to help

Comment: Hey man, being mean doesn't make you cool. You might know more than others but, what is the point of desouraging other for trying to help?

Comment: Being mean doesn't come from correcting others, it comes from the way you do it and they way you say it.